# Difference between Jquery Html callback function and append function?

Tags: jquery, html

What is the difference between Jquery Html callback function (source http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp) 
And Jquery append function (source http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp)

Also what ecsctly is the use of the parameter index in Jquery Html callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Callback**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp) is used to manipulate the content of html element. Here you can put your logic to handle the text provided and return your modified text.

In below code, it is adding original text with new one also return index. Same way you can put your own logic to handle text.

```
$("#test1").text(function(i, origText){
    return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world!
     (index: " + i + ")"; 
});
```

while in **[append](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp)** you got the choice to add some more text after the existing text and nothing can be done extra.

In below example, it is only appending the new text to the existing text.

```
$("p").append("Some appended text.");
```

Comment: But what is actual meaning and use of index, can you please elaborate?

Comment: index denotes the actual position of element in the set of element. see [this](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) for more information.